# taxonomy php else if statement not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, custom-taxonomy

Im trying to create a php else if statement for a custom taxonomy that I have created, however it seems to only show the first one? I have echoed out the variable and it is correct? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$genre = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'genre' );
if ($genre = "Action") {
  echo "Action" ;
} elseif ($genre = "Thriller") {
  echo "Thriller" ;
} elseif ($genre = "Horror") {
  echo "Horror" ;
}
?>
```

Comment: You could also use the [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement, since you are using `$genre` in every `if` condifition.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statements should be `if($variable == "something")`

Comparison operators are `==`, `===`, `!=`, `!==`, etc... [see more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Doing `$genre = "Action"` is assigning "Action" to `$genre`

A fix would be:

```
$genre = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'genre' );
if ($genre == "Action") {
  echo "Action" ;
} elseif ($genre == "Thriller") {
  echo "Thriller" ;
} elseif ($genre == "Horror") {
  echo "Horror" ;
}
```